Tanstack Router does not render redirected route after query error
I am using @tanstack/react-router and @tanstack/react-query in my React application. I have set up a QueryClient to handle errors and redirect to a login page if a 401 Unauthorized error occurs. However, after the redirection, the URL changes to /login but the content does not update to show the login page until I manually interact with the page (e.g., clicking a link).
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { RouterProvider, createRouter, redirect } from "@tanstack/react-router";
import { routeTree } from "./routeTree.gen";
import {
  QueryCache,
  QueryClient,
  QueryClientProvider,
} from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "@tanstack/react-query-devtools";
import "./index.css";
import "./i18n";

const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  queryCache: new QueryCache({
    onError: (error) => {
      router.navigate({ to: "/login" });
    },
  }),
});

export const router = createRouter({ routeTree, context: { queryClient } });

declare module "@tanstack/react-router" {
  interface Register {
    router: typeof router;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root")!;
if (!rootElement.innerHTML) {
  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);
  root.render(
    <StrictMode>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
        <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </StrictMode>
  );
}


You can check the unauthorize attempt by using beforeLoad in parent component. Like:
// src/routes/_authenticated.tsx
export const Route = createFileRoute('/_authenticated')({
  beforeLoad: async ({ location }) => {
    if (!isAuthenticated()) {
      throw redirect({
        to: '/login',
        search: {
          // Use the current location to power a redirect after login
          // (Do not use `router.state.resolvedLocation` as it can
          // potentially lag behind the actual current location)
          redirect: location.href,
        },
      })
    }
  },
})

Code Example
